# Get value from parent node child attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Im quite new to XLST. I have tried for a couple of weeks to transform a xml file to pure text file. I want to check for a specific attribute value and depending on the following attribute in parents child node print out a value.

I have tried different approaches and I'm completely confused and the code might look very confused.

Here is an extract of the xml I'm trying to work with:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LandXML xmlns="http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.2 http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.2/LandXML-1.2.xsd" version="1.2" date="2016-02-11" time="13:38:06" readOnly="false" language="English">
<HexagonLandXML xmlns="http://xml.hexagon.com/schema/HeXML-1.7" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xml.hexagon.com/schema/HeXML-1.7 http://xml.hexagon.com/schema/HeXML-1.7.xsd" xmlns:landxml="http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.2" averagingMode="Average" averagingMethod="Weighted" averagingPosLimit="0.050000" averagingHgtLimit="0.075000">
      <Point uniqueID="100" class="measured" subclass="GPS phase" lineworkFlag="FORT" averageUsage="true" applicationNumber="11"> 
        <Coordinates originalCoordSysKind="Ellipsoidal" originalGeodeticDatumKind="WGS84" originalHeightKind="ellipsoidal"> 
          <WGS84> 
            <Cartesian x="3374756.763053" y="893574.649632" z="5320249.612556"/>  
            <Geodetic lat="56.904101405681359" lon="14.830552433162786" hghtE="206.861483" hghthO="174.187582"/> 
          </WGS84>  
          <Local> 
            <Cartesian x="3374756.763053" y="893574.649632" z="5320249.612556"/>  
            <Geodetic lat="56.904101406543710" lon="14.830552433162786" hghtE="206.861556" hghthO="174.187583"/>  
            <Grid e="139675.834002" n="6309247.502715" hghtE="206.861556" hghthO="174.187583"/> 
          </Local> 
        </Coordinates>  
        <PointCode code="RKO" codeDesc="" codeGroup="TRANSPORT" codeLinework="open line"></PointCode>  
        <PointQuality Qxx="0.0003475127" Qxy="0.0000634192" Qxz="-0.0003087937" Qyy="0.0002335805" Qyz="-0.0001324870" Qzz="0.0014808670" MeanError="1.156631" CQ3D="0.052521" CQPos="0.027882" CQHeight="0.044509"/> 
      </Point>  
      <Point uniqueID="101" class="measured" subclass="GPS phase" averageUsage="true" applicationNumber="11"> 
        <Coordinates originalCoordSysKind="Ellipsoidal" originalGeodeticDatumKind="WGS84" originalHeightKind="ellipsoidal"> 
          <WGS84> 
            <Cartesian x="3374779.920766" y="893569.513712" z="5320236.614863"/>  
            <Geodetic lat="56.903879154810298" lon="14.830373667852458" hghtE="207.478635" hghthO="174.804021"/> 
          </WGS84>  
          <Local> 
            <Cartesian x="3374779.920766" y="893569.513712" z="5320236.614863"/>  
            <Geodetic lat="56.903879155672669" lon="14.830373667852458" hghtE="207.478708" hghthO="174.804022"/>  
            <Grid e="139664.880750" n="6309222.780312" hghtE="207.478708" hghthO="174.804022"/> 
          </Local> 
        </Coordinates>  
        <PointCode code="EBS" codeDesc="Belysningsstolpe" codeGroup="ELLEDNING" codeLinework="none"> 
          <Attribute name="Attribut 1" value="-5"/> 
        </PointCode>  
        <PointQuality Qxx="0.0001718767" Qxy="-0.0000094370" Qxz="0.0000030377" Qyy="0.0000956758" Qyz="-0.0000386372" Qzz="0.0007723176" MeanError="0.630108" CQ3D="0.020319" CQPos="0.010307" CQHeight="0.017511"/> 
      </Point> 
    </HexagonLandXML>
</LandXML>
```

And my current xls:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:landxml="http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.2" xmlns:hexagon="http://xml.hexagon.com/schema/HeXML-1.7" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="XML" select="/"/>
    <xsl:variable name="fileExt" select="'txt'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="fileDesc" select="'Output pointno, easting, northing, and ortho height to three decimal places. + handling of linecodes e.g. (40,41)'"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="$XML">
            <xsl:for-each select="landxml:LandXML">
                <xsl:for-each select="hexagon:HexagonLandXML">
                    <xsl:for-each select="hexagon:Point">

                        <xsl:for-each select="@uniqueID">
                            <xsl:value-of select="string(.)"/>
                            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:for-each>

                        <xsl:for-each select="hexagon:Coordinates">
                            <xsl:for-each select="hexagon:Local">
                                <xsl:for-each select="hexagon:Grid">
                                    <xsl:for-each select="@e">
                                        <xsl:value-of select='format-number(., "########.000")' />
                                        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="@n">
                                        <xsl:value-of select='format-number(., "########.000")' />
                                        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="@hghthO">
                                        <xsl:value-of select='format-number(., "########.000")' />
                                        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                                    </xsl:for-each>

                                </xsl:for-each>  
                            </xsl:for-each>  
                        </xsl:for-each>

                        <xsl:for-each select="hexagon:PointCode">
                            <xsl:value-of select="string(@code)"/>
                            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>

                            <xsl:if test="@codeLinework='open line'"  >
                                <xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:when test="../@lineworkFlag='START LINJE'">
                                        <xsl:text>40</xsl:text>
                                        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                                    </xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:when test="../following-sibling::*[1]/PointCode[@codeLinework='none']">
                                        <xsl:text>41</xsl:text>
                                        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                                    </xsl:when>

                                    <!-- <xsl:when test="../@codeLinework">
                                           <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                                           <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                                    </xsl:when>-->

                                </xsl:choose>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:if test="@codeLinework='none'">
                                <xsl:text>30</xsl:text>
                                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each>

                        <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>

                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So its this part that i can't get to work:

```xml
<xsl:when test="../following-sibling::*[1]/PointCode[@codeLinework='none']">
    <xsl:text>41</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>   
</xsl:when>
```

In short I want to check the value of the next  Point/PointCode/@codeLinework and print out a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'd be better if you could post the expected result, so we could provide more accurate answers. Even so, I tried based your comments and, with minor changes, created this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:landxml="http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.2"
    xmlns:hexxml="http://xml.hexagon.com/schema/HeXML-1.7"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="landxml:LandXML/hexxml:HexagonLandXML/hexxml:Point">          
            <xsl:for-each select="./hexxml:PointCode">
                <xsl:value-of select="string(@code)"/> 
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text> 

                <xsl:if test="@codeLinework='open line'"> 
                    <xsl:choose> 
                        <xsl:when test="../@lineworkFlag='START LINJE'"> 
                            <xsl:text>40</xsl:text> 
                            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text> 
                        </xsl:when> 
                        <xsl:when test="../following-sibling::*[1]/hexxml:PointCode[@codeLinework='none']"> 
                            <xsl:text>41</xsl:text> 
                            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text> 
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="../@codeLinework"> 
                            <xsl:text> </xsl:text> 
                            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text> 
                        </xsl:when> 
                    </xsl:choose> 
                </xsl:if> 
                <xsl:if test="@codeLinework='none'"> 
                    <xsl:text>30</xsl:text> 
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text> 
                </xsl:if> 
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I changed the selectors for Point and PointCode, as they were incorrect and I slightly changed the XPath expression you were trying to use for obtaining the following sibling.

Here's the output when I run against your XML:

`RKO,41,EBS,30,`

Comment: It seems that I can't use your xpath in my code. Could you please review what Im doing wrong. I can't get my head around xpath in the sibling context. I have added more code so you might see wha the problem is.

Comment: You should not expect that the XSLT runs when you change the structure of the source XML. I edited my answer accordingly, just making small changes: adding the namespaces of your XML to the stylesheet and changing the XPath expression to catch the new element names prefixed with the correct namespace. I didn't change the whole XSLT, just the part I developed. You should be able to integrate in yours now with no problems.

Comment: One for-each to many maybe :). Now it works thanks alot for your help but i dont understand the syntax "node:node/node:node". Is it a combination of Xpath and XLS?

Comment: The syntax is "nsprefix:node1/nsprefix:node2", where nsprefix is the namespace prefix that identifies the namespace of the XML element (e.g. "landxml" is the namespace prefix that identifies elements from the namespace http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.2, like LandXML). This is not specific to XPath or XSL, but to their basis: the XML standard.